# Editing a form is not working on react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am new on react. I am working on react application with redux. I have a form (I am using redux-form) by which I can save data or edit data.
my problem is , In edit mode I populate data using componentWillReceiveProps. and populated perfectly, now when I try to clear any field on form its again fill.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.props.dispatch(initialize('NewProject', nextProps.project.project[0]));
  }
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you're not dispatching this action somewhere else, like in `componentDidMount`? I can't say without seeing more code, but it's possible that whenever you edit your form, React again calls `componentWillReceiveProps` and overwrites whatever you did with the behavior you've given your component.

Per the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html):

> Note that React may call this method even if the props have not changed, so make sure to compare the current and next values if you only want to handle changes. This may occur when the parent component causes your component to re-render.

It may be a good idea for you to move your dispatch to a more predictable event if possible, like `componentDidMount`. Typically, your `render` method should be capable of handling different cases if a component has multiple possible states. You could also create an `edit` and `save` version of your component, and render one or the other based on the `props` you receive. The best way to "populate" data, as you put it, is to define `propTypes` for your component, and then use your `props` to insert that data into elements in the `render` method.

Comment: in componentDidMount i fetch the data from database
componentDidMount(){
    if(this.props.projectId){
      this.props.fectchProjectById(this.props.projectId);
    }
  }

Comment: Ok, I would recommend that, wherever you are fetching this data, after you're done, dispatch a new action with the relevant data in the payload. Write a reducer function that adds the new data to the current state, and then use `connect` to allow your component to map the new `state` to its `props`. Then your `render` method can decide what to do based on the props information. This is pretty much in keeping with [redux's defined data flow](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/DataFlow.html).